# How to make a function return data retrieved via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

In my javascript file, I use the function above to get asynchronously a value calculated by the server:

```
function function2(userid)
    {
        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost/bghitn/web/app_dev.php/get_number_of_articles",
                        data:{id:userid},
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){

                          return data;      
                        }
                        });

    }
```

In fact, I call the `function2` inside a set of functions:

```
function1();
var userid=.....
var x= function2(userid);
function3(x);
```

**The problem:**
as you see, `function3` uses the data returned by `function2`. But it seems that `function3` starts executing before the AJAX call is successfully finished. I tried to use the `when` function but in vain.

```
$.when(function2(userid)).done(function(){
function3();
        });
```

How to make the next javascript code executes after the preceding AJAX request is successfully performed? Your advices are highly appreciates.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, this isn't going to work. Pass a callback to the function and execute it when the ajax completes.

Comment: your second attempt almost works, but you have to return the promise. `return $.ajax(...)`

Comment: Thank you everybody.@JanDvorak The link provided is very useful

Comment: @JanDvorak, I thought I understood you last time, but in fact, I don't. I tried your remark but in vain. Is it the same idea behind the third option in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** You can always set your AJAX call to be synchronius, but be ready that the whole page stucks while waiting for response. just add parameter async: false to your set of parameters.

**Option 2:** Provide callbacks or put your future code inside success handler

**Option 3:** You can use defer/promise described here http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics

Comment: This is it, thank you very much. I will use the info provided, in addition to the link in comments of question.